# Change view to ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and forgive me for now. We have an existing Marionette BackboneJS application for our hospital. However, the code below is an example working BackboneJS Marionette where I want to replace Marionette with ReactJS view. This will help me tremendously on how I'll be able to migrate to ReactJS.

It would also be awesome if we can retrieve contentPlacement: "here" using an GET method call(xhr/ajax).

```
<header>
<h1>An Example BackboneJS Marionette</h1>
</header>

<article id="main">
</article>

<script type="text/html" id="sample-template">
  put some content <%= contentPlacement %>.
</script>
```

And below is the javascript code

```
// Define the app and a region to show content
// -------------------------------------------

var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
    "mainRegion": "#main" 
});

// Create a module to contain some functionality
// ---------------------------------------------

App.module("SampleModule", function(Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

    // Define a view to show
    // ---------------------

    var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#sample-template" 
    });

    // Define a controller to run this module
    // --------------------------------------

    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({

        initialize: function(options){
            this.region = options.region
        },

        show: function(){
            var model = new Backbone.Model({
                contentPlacement: "here"
            });

            var view = new MainView({
                model: model    
            });

            this.region.show(view);
        }

    });


    // Initialize this module when the app starts
    // ------------------------------------------

    Mod.addInitializer(function(){
        Mod.controller = new Controller({
            region: App.mainRegion
        });
        Mod.controller.show();
    });
});

// Start the app
// -------------

App.start();
```

Here is the jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvnwj2dp/1/

Can someone please guide me on how I will replace the Marionette with ReactJS for the view? A new code would really awesome!

UPDATE:

Here is my new jsfiddle. It's doing the REST api call but it's not updating the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/6df6a2zv/10/

```
var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var responseText = '';

console.log('executing the request ......');

$.ajax({
  url: url + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  responseText = data;
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({displayName: 'CommentBox',
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', {className: "commentBox"},
        "REST response:" + responseText
      )
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(CommentBox, null),
  document.getElementById('main')
);


// Define the app and a region to show content
// -------------------------------------------

// var App = new Marionette.Application();

// App.addRegions({
//    "mainRegion": "#main" 
// });

// Create a module to contain some functionality
// ---------------------------------------------

// App.module("SampleModule", function(Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

    // Define a view to show
    // ---------------------

//    var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
//        template: "#sample-template" 
//    });

    // Define a controller to run this module
    // --------------------------------------

//    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({

//        initialize: function(options){
//            this.region = options.region
//        },

//        show: function(){
//            var model = new Backbone.Model({
//                contentPlacement: "here"
//            });

 //           var view = new MainView({
//                model: model    
//            });

//            this.region.show(view);
//        }

//    });


    // Initialize this module when the app starts
    // ------------------------------------------

  //  Mod.addInitializer(function(){
 //       Mod.controller = new Controller({
//            region: App.mainRegion
//        });
 //       Mod.controller.show();
 //   });
// });

// Start the app
// -------------

// App.start();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to replace Marionette view with ReactJS view like what I wrote in the subject. Thank you so much. I updated my post and added at the end.

Comment: Please write my code

Comment: I'm going to try it now

Comment: @jantimon I've updated my stackoverflow post and I added a new ReactJS code. Unfortunately, it's not updating the DOM but I do see my ajax call in the Network tabl of my chrome dev tools. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

## Typescript CodePen Example

I am going to do a better write up soon but here is something close to what you are looking for. I am using Typescript and left the jsx out, because one I am not a big fan of it and two it adds another thing to learn and react can be a mental leap enough at times. See the codepen link below

Typescript is essentially ES6 with a good typing system, I like to think the types are actually quite helpful when trying to learn new code.

Remember react is just the view layer you will need something like Flux to drive it with data and a router, I recommend using react-router.

here are the types from the example, this should be the only really non-js looking piece of code.

```js
interface ViewProps { 
  children:any;
  id:string;
  headerTitle:string;
  bgColor?:string;
  className?:string;
}

interface ViewState {
  bgColor:string;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Thecavepeanut/pen/mVMVEx

Cheers,
Jake

NOTE: you can look at compiled JS on the codepen

Comment: I did not use your example since I was trying to show you a good example of how state should be safely updated and the most important thing to learn the component life cycle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example code. That will help me a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out

```
var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var responseText = '';

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'CommentBox',
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      response: ''
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: url + '/posts/1',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
      _this.setState({
        response: data
      });
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', {
          className: "commentBox"
        },
        "REST response:" + this.state.response.title
      )
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(CommentBox, null),
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```